# How to create .project description file in specific location of the project structure

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am working on tool where I have to create .project file in a specified location of the project.

Let's I have created a project from the tool "Test" and when I go to the navigator view i can get the .project file.

Then on right clicking of the project from the menu command let's say `"Generate code"` option is there and which is generating folders and files for my project.

But for my requirement I have to create another .project file in a specified location of the generated project, let's say `"Test->Generated folder->.project"`. Here I have to specify the project description.(Followed the standard project description). But I am getting

> workspaceclosedexception

while doing this.

in plugin.xml:
Include the project nature extension with id
Provide the class Name

```
public class MyProjectNAture extends IProjectNature
{
public static final NATURE_ID = "myNature";
//checked for the hasProhectNature()
}

public class MyWizard 

{
//Configured the projectnature while creating the project
if(specificCondition)
{
//with IProjectDescription including the project description
}
}
```

The issue is when I am running the jar file from the command prompt which is generated by the build of this project, getting workspaceclosedexception

What I did to create the .project file in my eclipse:
I have added resource nature extension and there in runtime I have defined my project nature and created the class which extends the IProjectNature. I have created an wizard where I have configured my project nature id.But the .project I have to create based on condition. That's why i'm getting the error. Can anybody suggest me how can I configure my .project file in specific location

Comment: Workspace closed exception means you are trying to use Eclipse APIs in a plain Java program - you can't do that, they only work in an Eclipse RCP or plug-in with a properly initialized workspace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that I can understand what you are trying to do. And I suggest you to separate the project creation ("org.eclipse.core.resources" API) and generation of some folders and files inside the existing IProject.
If you need to generate the .project file at some location you can just write the corresponding XML file there. Then you can open *another* project using this generated .project manifest.
Generally, the IProject can be created at any location URI supported by your target platform, but the .project manifest should always be in the "root" of this location.

Comment: yeah you are right Alexander, the .project manifest will be in root location. So is this feasible to create .project file in root of subfolder location?

Comment: You can do it with writing XML file to the location you need. This is the simplest solution.

Comment: Or, you can create **another** IProject in that subfolder location using https://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fcore%2Fresources%2FIProjectDescription.html&anchor=setLocationURI(java.net.URI)

Comment: Thank you Alex. Creating xml file and extending the class to IProject, it worked.